# Or relation in sails policies

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I have 4 policies in my sails app. lets say `p1,p2,p3,p4`. I have some actions lets say `a1,a2,a3,a4,a5` i need to apply policies using `AND` and `OR` combination.

```
a1 need ((p1 || p2) && p3)
a2 need (p1 || p3)
a3 need (p1 && p2)
a4 need (p1 || p4) 
a5 need (p1 && p2 && p4)
```

If i need to achieve above requirement. how do i write my policies?? For case `a5 need (p1 && p2 && p4)` i can simply write `a5: ['p1', 'p2','p3']` in my config/policies.js file. but how do i write for a1 to a4??

Comment: You cant have an `or` in policies  as they are nothing but express middleware where next() function is called on successful execution and stopped the execution if it fails. it has a serial pipeline behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible in Sails.